# PJSIP Siphon(ld: library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9)

Tags: ios, xcode, sip, voip, pjsip

Hi i am using the Siphon application to build my application. I have successfuly upload the binary to itunes store 3 months before. Now have to change the graphic of that app and trying to build the binary but it is giving me the following linker error. Any one can please guide me why it is so.

```
ld: library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

one thing more i have libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a library inside my project.

Comment: Check library search path under your target's build settings. Path needs to be set correctly.

Comment: Many thanks Yes i solve my problem by just removing the references of libraries and again copy the libraries. which create new paths for each library in project settings and problem solved.

Comment: i am wonder that xcode cannot handle that as all the libraries were inside the projects. i just remove and add again. but thank to you

Comment: @IQworldMaster : I am having the similar issue. Can you explain in detail what you did to solve that error? In my case, I am able to build the project to be run on simulator but when I tried to build it for iOS Device, I got the above mentioned error.

Comment: This Error occurs due to change of libraries path. just remove the library (remember remove by reference) and add again in the project it will automatically make your path correct.

Comment: @IQworldMaster: That's what you mentioned in your comment. I already tried that way. But it's not working for me. Can you add the link of error free code in your answer (I think that will be more helpful for future visitors)?

Comment: @IQworldMaster: Can you please help me with the source code (It's been 2 days since I stuck in this issue)?

Comment: can you please provide me the source code by any mean so that i can try it why it is not working for you.

Comment: @IQworldMaster: 1st of all there was an error : "framework not found IOKit". I tried to implement this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19201094/1603072). Now, I have around 60 Linker Errors in my code while running the app on device.

Comment: Please remove all the framework from your project and add again. Specially add the Security framework .

Comment: @IQworldMaster: It's not working. FYI, I am using this [source code](https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when we copy the project from one place to other. so the path of libraries become changed and 
we can solve it by just removing the required libraries by reference and copy the libraries again inside our project.