# Siphon builds for iOS simulator but getting linker error for device build

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, pjsip

I am a novice programmer working on 'Siphon' like application and looking for sample applications that could be used as reference for implementation. I tried [siphon open source](https://github.com/radif/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles) and I was able to compile it successfully for iOS simulator but when I select to build it for iOS device(iPhone 5 with iOS7), it fails to build with linker error saying,

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am having no clue why this error is occuring while building for device. I tried to resolve this by cleaning up derived data and compiling it again but still getting that error.

I want to compile it for iOS6 and iOS 7.

Need help to resolve this issue.

UPDATE 1: Complete description of error is as follows:

```
Ld /Users/NST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Siphon-eilljtdsvklgycghnbgzfjqfpozi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Siphon.app/Siphon normal armv7s
    cd /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/NST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Siphon-eilljtdsvklgycghnbgzfjqfpozi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-device/pjlib/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-device/pjlib-util/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-device/pjnath/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../sim-libs -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjlib/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjlib-util/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjnath/lib -L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib -F/Users/NST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Siphon-eilljtdsvklgycghnbgzfjqfpozi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/NST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Siphon-eilljtdsvklgycghnbgzfjqfpozi/Build/Intermediates/Siphon.build/Debug-iphoneos/Siphon.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Siphon.LinkFileList -dead_strip -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -lTelephonyIOKitDynamic -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework AddressBookUI -framework AddressBook -framework Foundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -lsqlite3.0 -framework CFNetwork -framework IOKit -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9 -lpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9 -lg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9 -lmilenage-arm-apple-darwin9 -lresample-arm-apple-darwin9 -lspeex-arm-apple-darwin9 -lsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9 -lg7221codec-i686-apple-darwin9 -lgsmcodec-i686-apple-darwin9 -lilbccodec-i686-apple-darwin9 -lmilenage-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpj-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjlib-util-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-audiodev-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-codec-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjmedia-videodev-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjnath-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjsdp-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-simple-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjsip-ua-i686-apple-darwin9 -lpjsua-i686-apple-darwin9 -lportaudio-i686-apple-darwin9 -lresample-i686-apple-darwin9 -lspeex-i686-apple-darwin9 -lsrtp-i686-apple-darwin9 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/NST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Siphon-eilljtdsvklgycghnbgzfjqfpozi/Build/Intermediates/Siphon.build/Debug-iphoneos/Siphon.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/Siphon_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/NST/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Siphon-eilljtdsvklgycghnbgzfjqfpozi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Siphon.app/Siphon

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../sim-libs'
ld: framework not found IOKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Update 2: I included `IOKit` Framework and now there are more errors,

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../sim-libs'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjlib/lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjlib/lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjlib-util/lib/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjlib-util/lib/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-videodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjsdp-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjnath/lib/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjnath/lib/libpjnath-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-ua-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsua-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-simple-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libilbccodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libmilenage-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libmilenage-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libg7221codec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libspeex-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libsrtp-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libresample-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libgsmcodec-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libgsmcodec-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libilbccodec-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libilbccodec-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libg7221codec-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libg7221codec-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libmilenage-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libmilenage-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjlib/lib/libpj-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjlib/lib/libpj-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjlib-util/lib/libpjlib-util-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjlib-util/lib/libpjlib-util-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-codec-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-codec-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-audiodev-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-device/third_party/lib/libgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-videodev-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-videodev-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjsdp-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjmedia/lib/libpjsdp-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjnath/lib/libpjnath-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjnath/lib/libpjnath-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-ua-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-ua-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libportaudio-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libportaudio-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsua-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsua-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libresample-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libresample-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libspeex-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libspeex-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-simple-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/pjsip/lib/libpjsip-simple-i686-apple-darwin9.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libsrtp-i686-apple-darwin9.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s): /Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/pjproject-2.0-simulator/third_party/lib/libsrtp-i686-apple-darwin9.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_pjsua_msg_data_init", referenced from:
      _sip_call_play_info_digits in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_call_set_user_data", referenced from:
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
      _sip_call_deinit_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_call_dial_dtmf", referenced from:
      _sip_call_play_digits in dtmf.o
  "_pjmedia_tonegen_stop", referenced from:
      _sip_call_play_digits in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_call_set_hold", referenced from:
      -[CallViewController setHoldEnabled:] in CallViewController.o
      -[CallViewController buttonClicked:] in CallViewController.o
  "_pjsua_conf_adjust_rx_level", referenced from:
      -[CallViewController setMute:] in CallViewController.o
  "_pjsua_call_get_max_count", referenced from:
      -[CallViewController findNextCall] in CallViewController.o
  "_pj_strdup_with_null", referenced from:
      -[CallViewController createCall:] in CallViewController.o
  "_pjsua_acc_add", referenced from:
      _sip_connect in call.o
  "_pjsua_destroy", referenced from:
      _sip_cleanup in call.o
  "_pjsip_parse_uri", referenced from:
      -[CallViewController createCall:] in CallViewController.o
  "_pjsua_conf_remove_port", referenced from:
      _sip_ring_deinit in ring.o
      _sip_call_deinit_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_conf_add_port", referenced from:
      _sip_ring_init in ring.o
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_call_hangup", referenced from:
      _sip_hangup in call.o
  "_pjsua_codec_set_priority", referenced from:
      _sip_manage_codec in call.o
  "_pj_log_5", referenced from:
      _sip_dial_with_uri in call.o
  "_pjsua_call_make_call", referenced from:
      _sip_dial_with_uri in call.o
  "_pj_log_3", referenced from:
      _on_mwi_info in call.o
  "_pjsua_acc_is_valid", referenced from:
      _sip_disconnect in call.o
  "_pjsua_call_get_user_data", referenced from:
      _sip_call_play_digits in dtmf.o
      _sip_call_deinit_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_acc_config_default", referenced from:
      _sip_connect in call.o
  "_pj_str", referenced from:
      _sip_connect in call.o
      _sip_dial_with_uri in call.o
      _sip_ring_init in ring.o
      -[CallViewController composeDTMF] in CallViewController.o
      _sip_call_play_digit in dtmf.o
      _sip_call_play_info_digit in dtmf.o
      _sip_call_play_info_digits in dtmf.o
      ...
  "_pjsua_perror", referenced from:
      _sip_connect in call.o
      _sip_dial_with_uri in call.o
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_acc_get_info", referenced from:
      _on_reg_state in call.o
  "_pjsua_call_get_info", referenced from:
      _on_call_state in call.o
      _on_call_media_state in call.o
      _on_incoming_call in call.o
      -[CallViewController timeout:] in CallViewController.o
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_create", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pj_pool_release", referenced from:
      _sip_cleanup in call.o
      -[CallViewController createCall:] in CallViewController.o
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
      _sip_call_deinit_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_pool_create", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
      -[CallViewController createCall:] in CallViewController.o
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pj_get_version", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pj_rand", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjsua_logging_config_default", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pj_pool_alloc", referenced from:
      _sip_connect in call.o
  "_pjmedia_tonegen_play_digits", referenced from:
      _sip_call_play_digits in dtmf.o
  "_pj_strdup2_with_null", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
      -[CallViewController createCall:] in CallViewController.o
  "_pjsua_conf_disconnect", referenced from:
      _sip_ring_stop in ring.o
  "_pjsua_call_answer", referenced from:
      _on_incoming_call in call.o
      _sip_answer in call.o
  "_pjmedia_tonegen_create2", referenced from:
      _sip_ring_init in ring.o
  "_pj_strdup3", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjsua_start", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjmedia_tonegen_rewind", referenced from:
      _sip_ring_stop in ring.o
  "_pjmedia_port_destroy", referenced from:
      _sip_ring_deinit in ring.o
      _sip_call_deinit_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_call_get_count", referenced from:
      -[SiphonApplication processCallState:] in SiphonApplication.o
      -[SiphonApplication callDisconnecting] in SiphonApplication.o
      -[CallViewController processCall:] in CallViewController.o
  "_pjsua_media_config_default", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjsua_transport_config_default", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjsua_conf_connect", referenced from:
      _on_call_media_state in call.o
      _sip_ringback_start in ring.o
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_config_default", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjsua_call_is_active", referenced from:
      -[CallViewController findNextCall] in CallViewController.o
  "_pj_log_get_level", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
      _on_call_state in call.o
      _on_incoming_call in call.o
      _on_mwi_info in call.o
      _sip_connect in call.o
      _sip_dial_with_uri in call.o
      _sip_manage_codec in call.o
      ...
  "_pjsua_transport_create", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjsua_verify_sip_url", referenced from:
      -[SiphonApplication application:handleOpenURL:] in SiphonApplication.o
      _sip_connect in call.o
      _sip_dial_with_uri in call.o
  "_pjsua_call_reinvite", referenced from:
      -[CallViewController setHoldEnabled:] in CallViewController.o
  "_pjmedia_tonegen_play", referenced from:
      _sip_ring_init in ring.o
  "_pj_log_1", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
      _on_call_state in call.o
      _on_incoming_call in call.o
      _sip_connect in call.o
      _sip_dial_with_uri in call.o
      _sip_manage_codec in call.o
  "_pj_pool_calloc", referenced from:
      _sip_call_play_digits in dtmf.o
      _pj_pool_zalloc in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_acc_del", referenced from:
      _sip_disconnect in call.o
  "_pjsua_call_send_request", referenced from:
      _sip_call_play_info_digits in dtmf.o
  "_pjsua_init", referenced from:
      _sip_startup in call.o
  "_pjsip_get_status_text", referenced from:
      -[SiphonApplication application:handleOpenURL:] in SiphonApplication.o
      -[SiphonApplication dialup:number:] in SiphonApplication.o
  "_pjmedia_tonegen_create", referenced from:
      _call_init_tonegen in dtmf.o
  "_pj_strerror", referenced from:
      -[SiphonApplication displayStatus:withTitle:] in SiphonApplication.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Hay, Have you got solution of this problem. I also facing same problem. So please help me your help very appriciatble .

Comment: yep search for 'idoubs' on github or google it for more details. You can customize it as well.Moreover, it is open source.

Comment: Dear i'm not able to find out it. and what is "idoubs"?

Comment: its a different open source project up to date and can be combined easily. See https://code.google.com/p/idoubs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real error is this

```
ld: framework not found IOKit
```

Your build tools cannot find the IOKit framework. In Xcode 5 there seems to be some issue in linking IOKit for device. You can check out [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542092/iokit-not-found) for workarounds.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes you are right. Now there are more errors. Check the errors i m getting now. I have updated the question.

Comment: @daemon22 Looks like you are building PJSIP as well. The error `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s: "_pjsua_msg_data_init"` suggests that it is not built for armv7s architecture.

Comment: @daemon22 Take a look at pjsip page on [how to build it for iOS](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#Supportingmultiplearchitecturesarmv6armv7armv7sandsoon) supporting various architectures.

Comment: I am a beginner in this. Need more help over it.
Can you help me?

Comment: @daemon22 I haven't worked on pjsip/siphon so I can just point you in correct direction. Please check [pjsip-ios page](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone), read the instructions and make necessary modification in the pjsip project included in the siphon project you are using.

Comment: Okk. I'll check that out.
Thanks for your response. :D

Comment: @daemon22 One simple workaround, Goto your Siphon project, Remove `armv7s` from `Valid architecture` in Build Settings. This should create build for armv7. However ideal solution would be to build pjsip for all supported archs.

Comment: Thanks, it compiled successfully if i remove armv7s from valid architecture field.
For ios7 I'll follow your link for compiling pjsip for armv7s.
Thanks again for your help. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/NST/Desktop/SIPHON-SIP-Client-that-actually-compiles-master/siphon/Siphon2/../../sim-libs'
>   ld: framework not found IOKit clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

You have to resolve that director and set the right path for the framework.
If the framework can't be found, there's no point in attempting to build it because even if it did run, it wouldn't work correct at all.

Comment: Okk.. Thanks for your response.
I'll try to include that framework but when i surfed internet for IOKit framework, it says IOKit framework is private and app would be rejected from APPLE if i used it. Though the app i am trying to compile is on app store.

Comment: Well first add the framework, if it works. It solves your problem. But it gives you another problem and tells you that you need to get a different framework.

Answer (score 0):

there are so many reason that you can occur error:

1.check the provisional profile and certificate.

2.set deployment target as per as your device ios.

3.check target membership for all .m file.

4.link all xib with correct outlets and mention code for device is iphone 5 or not if you are not using storyboard or autolayout.

Comment: i am using storyboards and provisional profile and certificate is correct.
Can you please tell what exactly i need to do for 'Target Membership'?

Comment: jsut click on any .m file (not appdelegate.m),and in file inspector ckeck whether you checkmark on target membership or not.if not, then checkmark it.

Comment: did you resolve it or send me ur code i will solve it.

Comment: I checked that. No problems were there. I missed including one framework. Please check the question. I have updated it and getting more errors now.

Comment: If you want to see the code you can download from the link i mentioned in the question.

Comment: may be your build architecture is not suitable for your ios deployment ttarget check it.